# Impacts of web.config and app.config changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I've a Windows Services written in c#.net. If I need to change the app.config file, do I need to restart the Windows Service application so that it picks up the new changes?

Also, if I change the web.config connection string does app pool gets started automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: its not the app pool that restarts but the app-domain for the particular web application. If it was the app pool (which is a IIS concept), it could in the worst case affect 100s of other websites as well if they are in the same app pool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes. Unless you implement some kind of automatic file watcher plus domain restart scheme, yes, app.config files for services or other types of apps need to be re-read in order for changes in them to be applied.

As for the second, yes, ASP.NET will detect changes to web.config files and reload the app domain automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to restart the service for it to take changes. Regarding the app pool it needs to be restarted also if you changed anything on the web.config for it to take the changes.

Comment: The default behavior is automatic app pool restarts for web.config changes. This can be disabled though.

Comment: And, even when enabled, it sometimes doesn't happen depending on the current traffic on the application.

Comment: @BNL its not the app pool that restarts but the app-domain for the particular web application. If it was the app pool (which is a IIS concept), it could in the worst case affect 100s of other websites as well if they are in the same app pool.

Comment: @PauliØsterø Thanks for the clarification, sloppy terminology on my part.

Answer (score 2):

Changes to web.config always restarts your web-application. Its not the same as the app-pool being recycled, but the particular App Domain gets unloaded and loaded again.

Regards to app.config, you can make all the changes to it you want, its just a file. Whether you need to restart your app depends on your logic, if you're only reading app-config during startup or during normal program execution as well.